# Azure Functions - Host.json not applying to Azure Application Settings

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

I'm at a complete loss here. I've just configured a new Azure Function app and created the following host.json file:

```html
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingExcludedTypes": "Request",
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true
      }
    }
  },
  "Values": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://test.test.com",
    "GrantType": "test",
    "ClientId": "test",
    "ClientSecret": "1234"
  }
}
```

For some reason, the settings under "Values" are not applying in the Azure portal. When I view the function settings none of these values show under "Application Settings" and I need to manually add them in order to allow the workflow to run. I've done some research and it seems to suggest that this is the expected outcome? IE: I'm supposed to configure these values on Azure?

I'm using the latest version of Azure Functions on .NET Core 3.1

Comment: host.json != settings.json => If you want to have settings you should use settings.json see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings)

Comment: azure function app settings is taking from the environment variables, and the env var is stored in different place in azure. On local, env var stored in local.settings.json, but on azure, it is stored in configuraion settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are publishing your app from Visual Studio, then as soon as you click on publish, you will see an option of Manage Application Setting,  there you can provide the setting, and it will be saved in your Azure Function Profile. That would be a one time process, until unless you are changing your settings.
[image]

Another option is that you can Azure Pipelines to deploy your function app, and then you can pass these values as a variable to pipeline

Comment: These methods ultimately pass the settings to configuration settings on azure. They are same basiclly.

Comment: @BowmanZhu, I agree with you :)  With the options I mentioned, we don't need explicit interaction with Azure.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you want to set some settings for your function app.

On local, the settings is stored in local.settings.json. But when you deploy your function app to Azure, the local.settings.json will not be uploaded. And on Azure, env variable is taking from the configuration settings instead of local.settings.json.

On portal, if you want to get env variable, you should save them in this place and don't forget to save:

[image]

Comment: Is this the only way of setting it? Can I not define it in a configuration file and have Azure populate from that?

Comment: @AdamCreed Normally, we use the method I mentioned in the answer to save the settings of azure function.

Comment: @AdamCreed I didn't find a set env variable method. The offcial doc just give the get env  method. So I think If you are talking about built-in method, then this is the only way to store env var.